# Hierarchy of classes in serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
public class A implements Serializable {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C implements Serializable extends B {}
public class D extends C {}
```

Is my judgment correct?

When serializing class `D`, all classes in the hierarchy are serialized because sub-classes are Serialized.

When deserializing class `D`, no default constructor is needed and the whole hierarchy is deserialized.

Comment: I don't think so.  If you serialize `D` then only `D` gets serialized, not the entire hierarchy.

Comment: @markspace You are incorrect. Interfaces of superclasses are inherited, and serialization includes all serializable superclasses. This is rather basic Java.

Comment: @EJP So are you saying that all classes are serializable?  Or are you saying that if `D` is serialized, its superclasses will be also?  I thought serialization included the data of a class, but did not include the .class files themselves.

Comment: @markspace That's three questions. (1) No, of course not. I can't imagine why you're even asking. (2) Yes, insofar as they are serializable. That stops with `java.lang.Object` in this case. (3) It does not include the .class file, and there is nothing here that suggests otherwise. There is no logical connection between any of these questions, and (1) and (3) have nothing to do with anything that has been written here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Since the top-level class `A` implements `Serializable`, and classes inherit interfaces from their superclasses, all of your classes are serializable. No default constructors are necessary because all of the classes indicate, by being serializable, that they can be safely reconstituted by reading their state from the stream.

Answer (score 2):

> In Serialization class D flow, [is] all hierarchy serialized because sub-classes are Serialized.

No, it is all serialized because the *base* class `A` is *`Serializable`*.

> In Deserialization class D flow, any no parameter constructor not need and all hierarchy deserialized.

Correct. The nearest non-serializable base class of `A` would need a no-args constructor, but in this case it is `java.lang.Object`, which does.

Comment: Since you quoted, heads up that I copy edited extensively.

Comment: @chrylis Well you shouldn't have. OP is entitled to state his reasons and have them confirmed or corrected.

Comment: I said *copy-edited*. I retained the author's sense but fixed the English.

Comment: @chrylis You removed the words 'because sub-classes are Serialized'. That's not copy-editing and it is not retaining the author's sense either. Don't do that.

Comment: Then I misparsed that phrase, and you were right to re-add that.